# How can I build an array with the contents of multiple HTML tags with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html

The question is this: in my HTML document I have multiple P tags with the price class, for example `<p class = "price">` `400` `</ p>`. And what I want to do is build an array that contains the values ​​of all those paragraphs.

The intention of creating this array is to be able to filter them with javascript through filter () and make the paragraphs disappear or appear if they comply with x condition

Comment: please add code snippets to show what you have tried, what is not working or what problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not to generate array and filter them. You can simply loop through all the elements, check the text and set the style property:

```js
var pList = document.querySelectorAll('p.price');
var hidePriceLess = 300;
pList.forEach(p => p.textContent < hidePriceLess? p.style.display='none':'');
```

```html
<p class="price">100</p>
<p class="price">200</p>
<p class="price">300</p>
<p class="price">400</p>
<p class="price">500</p>
```

Comment: Yes ... I realized that it was not necessary to create an array to filter the html elements. I ended up doing a code very similar to yours but with a conditional in a "for of"

Answer (score 0):

thought  you can already get array from selectors .but if  for type intellicense and all

Could  Array.from fit your requirement. pass any  selector  to it.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".price"))
```